# Is (log n)^k = O(n^1/2)? For k greater or equal to 0

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

In big-O notation is `O((log n)^k) = O(log n)`, where `k` is some constant right? So what's happening with the `(log n)^k` when `k>=0`?

Comment: `O(log(n^k)) = O(log n)` is true, but not what you wrote.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Maroun Hmmm i think about that aswell but i saw that (check the last answer): [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523070/what-is-the-big-o-of-the-function-log-n2-logn) and i wanted to ask again to be sure !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O((log n) * k) == O(log n), but (log n)^k is definitely **not** the same thing.  I believe you're thinking of constant multiplication, which is equivalent in big O notation.  However, raising f(n) to a power changes the time to completion.  This is the same concept as O(n) being different from O(n^2).

Comment: So the right answer to that is : O((log n)^k) = O(log n) for k>=0?

Comment: No, O((log n)^k) = O(log n) for k == 1, it = O(1) for k==0 of course, and everything else it is bigger.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer , i will have to study more as it seems !

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this might be the source of the misunderstanding?
log(n^k) = k * log(n), but no such simplification works for log(n)^k = (log(n))^k.

Comment: I see but look here the last answer : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523070/what-is-the-big-o-of-the-function-log-n2-logn)